# DataStax Enterpise on AWS - Futures Timed Out After [120] when running Spark job

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise

We are currently running into the following error when attempting to run a Spark Job on DSE 4.8 Analytics

> ERROR 2016-04-11 20:59:42,825 UserGroupInformation.java:1128 -
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:
>   PriviledgedActionException as:ubuntu
>   cause:java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after
>   [120 seconds] Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.DseSecureRunner.(DseSecureRunner.scala:24)     at
>   org.apache.spark.DseSecureRunner$.main(DseSecureRunner.scala:34)  at
>   org.apache.spark.DseSecureRunner.main(DseSecureRunner.scala) Caused
>   by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: Unknown exception
>   in doAs   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1138)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120
>   seconds]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1125)
>     ... 11 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures
>   timed out after [120 seconds]     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
>     at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
>     at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:97)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:67)
>     ... 14 more

This error occurs on the 2 worker nodes, while the node which is running the driver runs fine.

We have the following Security Group configuration for a Cluster of 3 nodes created using the DataStax AMI of the 2.6 flavor

Scraped from the documentation my Security Group is like this with one minor exception

The following port was ignored

8983    Custom TCP Rule TCP 0.0.0.0/0   Solr port and Demo applications web site port (Portfolio, Search, Search log, Weather Sensors)

[image]

The only way to get around this error was to do the following
ALL TCP
TCP (6)
ALL
cluster-security-group (using the picture as reference this would be sg-bbc40aff)

Which leads me to believe that some process is trying to communicate with nodes in the cluster via another port.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/install/installAMIsecurity.html

Has anyone ran into this problem running Spark Jobs using DSE Analytics on AWS? 
Thanks

Comment: Note that a lot of the spark ports are random so you're going to want the DSE Analytics machines to have network access across all ports http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#configuring-ports-for-network-security  These aren't in the datastax page because the client does not need access to the ports. It's only inter-node.

Comment: Thanks, I guess opening all the ports to the clusters security group is the best way to ensure Spark can communicate within the cluster.